# vbs msiexec /x coding incorrect

Tags: vbscript

I am unfamiliar with vbs. I have tried several variations of this. I am trying to do an uninstall prerequisite before installing the software update. I also want this to uninstall silently. Any help with this is appreciated.

```
Set oWMIroot = GetObject("WinMgmts:root/cimv2")
Set oWMIColl = oWMIroot.ExecQuery("Select IdentifyingNumber, Name  FROM Win32_Product") 
  For Each oWMIval In oWMIColl
if oWMIval.Name = "John's MIND" then
 'WScript.Echo oWMIval.Name & " = " & oWMIval.IdentifyingNumber ' this is correct

  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  WshShell.Run "msiexec /x  oWMIval.IdentifyingNumber",1,True

End if
Next
```

If I replace `oWMIval.IdentifyingNumber` with the actual GUID it works. 
Thanks

Comment: This is a common mistake, covered in the VBScript [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info).

Answer (score 0):

```
WshShell.Run "msiexec /x " & oWMIval.IdentifyingNumber,1,True
```

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated. I added msiexec /qb /x to avoid the "are you sure screen"

Comment: Adding some information as to why the modification solves the problem would make this a better answer.